# Updated alternative to AntiFreeze

Tags: windows-10, task-management

> AntiFreeze - version 1.01 released: December 2007 website: 
>   http://www.resplendence.com/antifreeze Copyright © 1997-2007
>   Resplendence Software Projects Sp.
>
> AntiFreeze is an emergency task manager utility. It offers a last
>   recourse when you find your computer in a hung state. Because programs
>   consume too much CPU or too much memory or too many programs have been
>   started, your computer has become unresponsive. The mouse still moves
>   but programs are not responding, you cannot switch to other programs
>   or even close them. You have even tried to start the Windows Task
>   Manager but even that won’t work because it does not get enough
>   attention from the scheduler to respond to your mouse clicks and
>   keyboard presses. You are ready to press the reset button. Instead you
>   can press the hotkey of AntiFreeze. It will put to sleep all running
>   programs except the most critical ones, giving you the opportunity to
>   close down the programs which are causing problems. You may even be
>   able to save or recover your work.
>
> AntiFreeze works on Windows Vista, Windows XP and Windows 2003 Server
>   both x86 and x64 editions.

I was wondering if anything like this exists for Windows 10

Comment: It's of course a shame that such a utility even needs to exists (as in, this kind of functionality should be in the OS), but hey, there it is.

Answer (score 1):

[WhySoSlow](http://www.resplendence.com/whysoslow) from the same company supports Windows 10, *and 7, 8, 8.1 & server 2012* and will include all of the functionality of Antifreeze, *it is in Beta at the time of writing 20-Aug-2016*.

It also provides data gathering on which programs are resource hungry and other advisory tools.

**N.B.** *I am not associated with the company concerned in any way*

Comment: `This version will stop working after August 21, 2016 ` I hate when developers time-bomb their beta releases.

Comment: @beppe9000 Me to but there is at least the feedback option & the date suggests coming out of beta soon.

Comment: @beppe9000 - N.B. They have a new beta with an expiry date of September 21, 2016 - worth looking at the free pro licence for useful feedback offer as well.

Comment: I tried it, but it is heavily bugged on Windows 10: the emergency task manager interface is unresponsive and the report function is alpha quality. I will wait until this product evolves, but looks good.

Comment: @beppe9000 - I suspect that the above is exactly the sort of feedback - with a little more details - that the developers are looking for _and which might qualify you for the free licence_ so I would suggest doing a detailed feed back to them.